# isNaN then show not working

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this simple autocomplete with JSON results. Suppose in case there is no value fit to display a div (so the user can create a new entity), and I can't understand why it's not displaying the hidden div.

```
public JsonResult GetSubjectsName(string term)
{
    var results = db.subjects.Where(s => term == null || s.SubjectName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
        .Select(x => new 
        { 
            id = x.SubjectId, 
            value = x.SubjectName 
        }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

```html
<div id="divId" style="background-color: red; height: 250px; display: none">
    blabla
</div>
```

```js
$("#term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetSubjectsName",
            data: "{'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    if (isNaN(item.id)) {
                        $("#divId").show("slow");
                    };
                    return {
                        label: item.value,
                        value: item.value,
                        id: item.id,
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `List` of subjects, which I assume all will have an `id`.

So your check, instead of `if isNaN` could be to check the `length`:-

```
success: function(data) {

  if (!data.length) {

    $("#divId").show("slow");

  } else {

    response($.map(data, function(item) {
      return {
        label: item.value,
        value: item.value,
        id: item.id,
      }
    }));

  }
}
```